# Should I use clear grain filler on this oak table?

Tags: furniture, refinishing

Currently at the end stages of stripping and refinishing a painted-over vintage oak table. After stripping off several coats of paint and careful sanding it has a nice natural pickled look to it. Would clear grain filler, no stain, and poly work for this project? This is only my second project so any input would be appreciated.

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c58Az.jpg

Comment: The woodworking stack  Exchange  would be a more appropriate place for this question,

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.